# Elec hot water tank

Tags: water-tank

I just left my house on a vac and turned off the water but forgot to kick the hot water breaker , is this going to be a problem for me ?

Comment: Why did you turn off the water?  The only time I've heard of folks doing that is if they shut down for a season; and even then if it's winter you'd need to drain all the pipes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the taps are off it should be fine.  The water will stay in the tank.  It will waste some hydro, but shouldn't destroy the tank.

Comment: To elaborate: The tank **should** have not only a thermostat to limit max water temp, but if for any reason the water level drops inside the tank, there also should be a sensor which shuts down the heater when empty.

Comment: Thanks it a vac home and will not be back till October but I had a bro in law turn it off tomorrow